# Organize values of unique elements based on occurrence time Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, unique, transpose

Please help in this. I have the 2 arrays below. Array a contains hours and array b contain the same hours and then values that happened at those hours.

```
a = ["1015","1240","1732"]
b = ["1015","X|2","D|5","1240","B|11","F|8","X|7","1732","D|9","X|1","B|3"]
```

So in array b:

Elements `"X|2","D|5"` happened at hour 10:15

Elements `"B|11","F|8","X|7"` happened at hour 12:40

Elements `"D|9","X|1","B|3"` happened at hour 17:32

First part of each element in B could be repeated, for example, X happened in 3 hours with different values, so in the output, I´d like to print hours and unique values,
this is X, D, B and F

The output I´m looking for is:

```
HOUR    X    D    B    F 
1015    2    5
1240    7         11   8
1732    1    9    3
```

The code I have so far is below but I still not able to organize the output in desired order.

```
val=[]
headers=[]
b.each{|v|
if v.include? "|"
    headers << v.split("|")[0]
    val << v.split("|")[1]
else
    val << ["HOUR",v]
end
}

puts ["HOURS",headers.uniq].join(" ")
puts val
```

Current output of my code:

```
HOURS X D B F

HOUR
1015
2
5
HOUR
1240
11
8
7
HOUR
1732
9
1
3
```

Comment: What is the significance of array `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assumed that `a` merely contains the times in `b`, sorted. As that can be computed there is no need to provide that information as an input.

**Code**

```
def print_table(data, time_label, column_spacing)
  h = data.slice_before { |s| !s.include?('|') }.
           each_with_object({}) { |(t,*a),h|
             h[t] = a.map { |s| s.split('|') }.to_h.tap { |g| g.default = '' } }
  row_labels = h.keys.sort
  column_labels = h.values_at(*row_labels).reduce([]) { |a,g| a | g.keys }
  image = [[time_label, *column_labels],
          *row_labels.map { |time| [time, *h[time].values_at(*column_labels)] }]
  row_label_width, *column_widths = image.transpose.map { |r| r.map(&:size).max }
  print_image(image, row_label_width, column_widths, column_spacing)
end

def print_image(image, row_label_width, column_widths, column_spacing)
  image.each do |time, *values|
    print time.ljust(row_label_width)
    values.zip(column_widths).each { |s,width| print s.rjust(width + column_spacing) }
    puts
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
b = ["1240", "B|11", "F|8", "X|7",
     "1015", "X|2",  "D|5",
     "1732", "D|9",  "X|1", "B|3"]
time_label = "HOUR"
column_spacing = 2

print_table(b, time_label, column_spacing)
```

prints

```
HOUR  X  D   B  F
1015  2  5
1240  7     11  8
1732  1  9   3
```

Note that the times-of-day in `b` are not in sorted order.

**Explanation**

For the values in the *Example* section, the first step is to group the elements of the array `b` into groupings (arrays) by time-of-day.

```
groups = b.slice_before { |s| !s.include?('|') }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x000000022b2490>:each>
```

See [Enumerable#slice_before](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before). We can see the objects that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
 groups.to_a
   #=> [["1240", "B|11", "F|8", "X|7"],
   #    ["1015", "X|2", "D|5"],
   #    ["1732", "D|9", "X|1", "B|3"]]
```

Next, let's convert `groups` to a hash.

```
h = groups.each_with_object({}) { |(t,*a),h|
  h[t] = a.map { |s| s.split('|') }.
           to_h.
           tap { |g| g.default = '' } }
  #=> {"1240"=>{"B"=>"11", "F"=>"8", "X"=>"7"},
  #    "1015"=>{"X"=>"2", "D"=>"5"},
  #    "1732"=>{"D"=>"9", "X"=>"1", "B"=>"3"}}
```

See [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h), [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) and [Hash#default=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D). `g.default = ''` assigns the hash a default value of an empty space. This means that `g[k]` returns an empty space if `g` does not have a key `k`. For example, `h["1015"]["B"] #=> ""`. `g.default = ''` returns `''`, which is why it is is enclosed in a `tap` block, which returns `g` with the default defined.

[This article](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) provides an explanation of the use of the *splat* operator. (Here, in a nutshell: `[1, *[2, 3]] #=> [1, 2, 3]`).

For the column labels we have a few options. Regardless, we first need the unique keys in the values (hashes) of `h` corresponding  to the keys in `row_labels`.

```
row_labels = h.keys.sort
  #=> ["1015", "1240", "1732"]
column_labels = h.values_at(*row_labels)
  #=> [{"X"=>"2", "D"=>"5"},
  #    {"B"=>"11", "F"=>"8", "X"=>"7"},
  #    {"D"=>"9", "X"=>"1", "B"=>"3"}]
column_labels = column_labels.reduce([]) { |a,g| a | g.keys }
  #=> ["X", "D", "B", "F"]
```

See [Enumerable#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at), [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`) and [Array#|](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-7C). I have assumed this gives the desired column order, but the elements of `column_labels` could be reordered if desired. I present two possible options in the last section of my answer.

We next construct an array containing all the values in the table to be printed.

```
image = [[time_label, *column_labels],
          *row_labels.map { |time| [time, *h[time].values_at(*column_labels)] }]
  #=> [["HOUR", "X", "D", "B", "F"],
  #    ["1015", "2", "5", "", ""],
  #    ["1240", "7", "", "11", "8"],
  #    ["1732", "1", "9", "3", ""]]
```

`Enumerable#values_at` pulls out the values (hashes) in `h[time]` that correspond to each rows of the table, in their desired order.

We may then print the table as follows.

```
row_label_width, *column_widths = image.transpose.map { |r| r.map(&:size).max }
  # => [4, 1, 1, 2, 1]
```

so that

```
row_label_width
  #=> 4
column_widths
  #=> [1, 1, 2, 1]

image.each do |time, *values|
  print time.ljust(row_label_width)
  values.zip(column_widths).each { |s,width| print s.rjust(width + column_spacing) }
  puts
end
```

prints the table shown in the *Example* section.

**Column order**

As I said earlier the elements of `column_labels` could be reordered if desired.  One possibility is to sort the labels alphabetically.

```
column_labels = h.values_at(*row_labels).reduce([]) { |a,g| a | g.keys }.sort!
  #=> ["B", "D", "F", "X"]
```

Another is that we are given a desired order of all possible column labels.

```
desired = ["Y", "F", "D", "Z", "B", "X"]
```

Then compute the following.

```
column_labels = desired & h.values_at(*row_labels).reduce([]) { |a,g| a | g.keys }
  #=> ["F", "D", "B", "X"]
```

Comment: Hi Cary, it works wonderful, just awesome! Is a general solution for what I see tested. The column spacing is great additional feature that orders the output and looks very clean. Thanks one more time for helo and explanation either. It´ll help many people in the future.

Comment: Ger, I am glad to hear this has been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure if you would ever need the `a` array since all its values also occur within `b` array - I am leaving it out of my code.

What it is doing in the first step: it reduces the original array into a new one, which combines the hours and what happened in them into sub-arrays. I do this by checking if the current value is numeric if not, I write a new action into the current hour - and at the same time, I am keeping track of all the possible columns in the right order.

```
columns = ["HOUR"]
merged = b.reduce([]) do |accumulator, value| 
  if value =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\Z/
    accumulator.push({"HOUR" => value})
  else
    parts = value.split('|')
    columns.push(parts[0]) unless columns.include?(parts[0])
    accumulator[-1][parts[0]] = parts[1]
  end
  accumulator
end
```

`merged` is now `[{"HOUR"=>"1015", "X"=>"2", "D"=>"5"}, {"HOUR"=>"1240", "B"=>"11", "F"=>"8", "X"=>"7"}, {"HOUR"=>"1732", "D"=>"9", "X"=>"1", "B"=>"3"}]` - and `columns` is now `["HOUR", "X", "D", "B", "F"]`

Going from there, we can prepare the data csv-like:

```
csv_like = [columns] + merged.map { |dataset| columns.map { |column| dataset.fetch(column, nil) } }
```

`csv_like` is now `[["HOUR", "X", "D", "B", "F"], ["1015", "2", "5", nil, nil], ["1240", "7", nil, "11", "8"], ["1732", "1", "9", "3", nil]]`

This should be what you were searching for - you can easily create a CSV or HTML table with this data now.

Comment: Hi wiesion, Thanks a lot for provide help to me. It worked just fine and I was able to iterate the csv_like in the way I need too.